# Python - plotly hover icon not working

Tags: python, plotly

As far as I'm aware, I've copied the documentation exactly. I basically used the documentation code and tweaked it for my purposes. But when I run this bit of code, no hover feature with text appears on my plot.

```
#Initialize df
aviation_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Latitude","Longitude","Fatalities"])
aviation_data["Latitude"] = [40.53666,60.94444]
aviation_data["Longitude"] = [-81.955833,-159.620834]
aviation_data["Fatalities"] = [True,False]

#Initialize colorscale
scl = [[0,"rgb(216,15,15)"],[1,"rgb(5,10,172)"]]

#Initialize text data
text_df = "Fatal: " + aviation_data["Fatalities"].apply(lambda x: str(np.bool(x))) + '<br>' + \
    "Latitude: " + aviation_data["Latitude"].apply(lambda x: str(x)) + '<br>' + \
    "Longitude" + aviation_data["Longitude"].apply(lambda x: str(x))

#Initialize data
data = [ dict(
    type = 'scattergeo',
    locationmode = 'USA-states',
    lon = aviation_data["Longitude"],
    lat = aviation_data["Latitude"],
    text = text_df,
    mode = 'markers',
    marker = dict( 
        size = 5, 
        opacity = 0.5,
        reversescale=True,
        autocolorscale=False,
        symbol = 'circle',
        line = dict(
            width=1,
            color='rgba(102, 102, 102)'
        ),
        colorscale = scl,
        cmin = 0,
        color = aviation_data["Fatalities"].astype(int),
        cmax = 1
    ))]

#Initialize layout
layout = dict(
    title ='Aviation Incidents for the Years 2014-2016<br>\
    (red indicates fatal incident, blue indicates non-fatal)',
    geo = dict(
        scope='usa',
        projection=dict(type='albers usa'),
        showland = True,
        landcolor = "rgb(206, 206, 206)",
        countrywidth = 0.5,
        subunitwidth = 0.5        
    ),
)

#Plot
fig = dict(data=data,layout=layout)
iplot(fig,validate=False)
```

Anyone know why my hover text isn't showing up?

Comment: Where does aviation_data come from?

Comment: @MaximilianPeters, it's a dataset that I downloaded from [here](https://www.ntsb.gov/_layouts/ntsb.aviation/index.aspx). I've cleaned it a lot since I've downloaded it though.

Comment: Thanks for the info! It's always much easier to get help if you have a minimal example which people can just run (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In this case a few lines from your cleaned data would be sufficient.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters, I just edited the block of code so that it is self contained and can be run as is.

Comment: your code works fine in my iPython notebook.

Comment: Including the hover text? It's displaying the latitude, longitude, and fatality for each marker?

Comment: Yes, two dots with hover text. What systems are you using?

Comment: I'm on a Fedora 24 linux system, running the latest version of Anaconda, with plotly 2.0.2 installed.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters I would like to follow up on this, but since I'm a new user I just barely received the chat privilege. Can we open up another chat?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137971/question-42351508

Answer (score 0):

In the last line of code you need to call this:

```
plotly.offline.plot(fig, validate=False)
```

Instead of:

```
iplot(fig, validate=False)
```

Also do not forget import plotly:

```
import plotly
```

Hope this will help